# How to stop listening at Port 135?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-registry, port, sockets

I am learning **Socket Programming** (TCP server) On Windows 7, but an error message that keeps coming is:

> port 135 is in use.

I can see Port 135 listening through `netstat`. So , I want to stop port 135 to make the TCP server program run.

I have done the following things.

1. Navigate over to the key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\OLE`
2. At the right column, locate the value `EnableDCOM` and modify the value to `N`.
3. Navigate to this registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\RPC`
4. Right click on & Modify the value named `DCOM Protocols` Under the key `Value Data`, you will see values like below (or something similar). These values keep Port 135 open. Highlight everything listed and delete all existing data, thus disabling the `DCOM` service through `dcomcnfg`.

But the Port 135 is still listening. How do I stop listening on that port?

I found the instructions here:

http://www.pimp-my-rig.com/2008/10/faq-disable-port-135-disable-dcom.html#sthash.Bt1qMvEf.dpuf

Comment: What is your outer problem? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Actually i am trying socket programming (TCP server) but the error is coming as port 135 is in use and i can see port 135 listening through netstat. So , i want to stop port 135 to make TCP server program run.

Comment: Change your program to use an unprivileged port (greater than or equal to 1,024).

Comment: Port 135 is already officially registered. You should use unregistered ports. IANA maintains the [Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml). You take your chances when using a registered port.

Answer (score 4):

I have same question.

TCP port 135 is shared by DCOM(based on RPC) and Raw RPC server component as a public entrance of TCP/UDP/NamedPipe transport layer which is chosen by each DCOM/Raw RPC server component, so it's not simple as "disabling DCOM on this computer" will stop port 135.

Currently, i disable port 135 by adding firewall rule(disable 135) manually:

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="stop listening at TCP port 135" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=135 action=block enable=yes`

Having testded RPC 135 port via tools rpcdump.py [impacket](https://github.com/CoreSecurity/impacket) open source project and something else concerned,
i have confirmed something about TCP port 135:

1. Anyone can connect to TCP port 135 then get RPC interfaces list without
   any permission.
2. Further usage on such RPC interfaces require authentication which i
   have not figured out how authentication works on TCP port 135.
3. Disabling TCP port 135 will NOT affect SMB(Windows File Sharing etc...,
   you can still use psexec/mmc/registry from client machine to access this machine, this is because they all call
   RPC via SMB(TCP port 445)).
4. Disabling TCP port 135 will NOT affect Local DCOM/Raw RPC server
   component because they do not need network.
5. Disabling TCP port 135 will only affect some client machine which directly use  DCOM remote activation (i.e. VB
   CreateObject("Excel.Application", RemoteMachine) ), or raw RPC binding on RemoteMachine(i.e, some windows old style internal management service)

The conclusion is that TCP port 135 is not useful for most non-server computer.

For server computer, i have not tested too much, seems something like "DFS Management" service automatically added firewall rule to enable the port.

Some external references:

- [Windows
  Network Services](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/articles/win_net_srv/)
- [rpcdump.py](https://github.com/CoreSecurity/impacket/pull/118)

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: @HackSlash It is an answer. I could not "stop listening at port 135" because many processes depends on it under the ground, and the system would not let you stop RPC service. So I chose an alternative way: disable incoming request to port 135.

Answer (score -1):

You might find [DCOMbobulator](https://www.grc.com/freeware/dcom.htm) useful for this.