How to block port 135 on Windows 11 using Windows Firewall?
I was able to create a rule to block port 135 using Windows Firewall. However when looking at nmap output. The port is still open.

How can I successfully block this port on Windows 11?
Thanks

How did you create the rule?

@music2myear Using the Windows Firewall GUI.

Port 135 is used by several possible services built-in to Windows: https://superuser.com/questions/669199/how-to-stop-listening-at-port-135 and so your telling the firewall to close it may be ignored by the OS still requiring it.

No, I'm asking the specific steps you did IN the firewall to block port 135. Please try to be as specific as you can be. Understanding HOW you think you've blocked it will hopefully give us more of the information we need to get you good answers.

@music2myear Oh I see, I know in Linux there is this concept of local only sockets, Does Windows have this concept and if so can RPC be switched to that mode so I can turn off the TCP Port?

A quick web search suggests this from our sister site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041306/is-it-possible-to-open-a-local-machine-only-socket-on-windows

@music2myear I selected Inbound Rules in the left Pane and followed the dialogs after clicking New Rule in the right pane. Then it showed up in the Inbound Rules list enabled for all profiles.
